# How disable assets compilation on heroku?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets, precompile

I'm trying to deploy my rails app to heroku using this turtorial:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

So, I use rails 4.1.1 and ruby 2.1.1

My Gemfile has `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` inside.

My application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Charticus
  class Application  Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

I created file `public/assets/manifest.yml`

But when I deploy app to heroku - it compile all my js-files files to application.js and all css-files application.css. And I can't see it on app.heroku.com using firebug.

What I need to do with my configurations to see all my js and css files on app.heroku.com ?
How disable assets precompiling and minification on heroku?

Help me please!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compare `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`.

And make production.rb asset configs like in development.rb:

Comment this lines:

- `config.serve_static_assets = false`
- `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier`
- `config.assets.compile = false`
- `config.assets.digest = true`

Then:

1. Push my changes to git repo `git push origin master`
2. Push changes to heroku `git push heroku master`

Comment: I had to add the setting `config.assets.debug = true` as well.

Comment: This doesn't prevent Heroku's Ruby buildpack from calling the `rake assets:precompile` rake task.  It just configures the production environment to be like the development environment.

Answer (score 11):

**lib/tasks/assets.rake**

```
Rake::Task["assets:precompile"].clear
   namespace :assets do
     task 'precompile' do
     puts "Not pre-compiling assets..."
   end
end
```

You are done.

Comment: In my case I had to write it on `Rakefile`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 applications have a `manifest-*.json` file, not a `manifest.yml` file. This file is typically generated when you run `rake assets:precompile` , how are you compiling your assets?

Regardless, you need a file `public/assets/manifest-(fingerprint).json` file

Comment: I create public/assets/manifest-(fingerprint).json, and now heroku app cannot find application.css and application.js ...

Comment: what are you trying to do? Are you running asset compilation locally? Then manifest file is created for you. It's not just a blank file...

Answer (score 0):

Fast forward to 2018, and you would need to add the following to `config/initializers/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Then you'd need to customize [Heroku's Ruby Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby) to not run the `assets:precompile` rake task.  I won't provide a link to such a buildpack because I won't support or warrant one, but its pretty easy to find it in `lib/language_pack/ruby.rb` and start removing relevant code.

You'd then have to configure your Heroku app to use your new forked Buildpack instead of the default one (e.g. using `heroku buildpacks`).

Thats the cleanest way to disable the asset pipeline in a Heroku app w/ Rails, without resorting to overriding Rails' built-in rake tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Fast forward to 2021 and Rails 6.x, if you completely removed Webpacker and Sprockets/Asset Pipeline, replace the `bin/yarn` file content with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'Yarn not present, nothing to do.'
```

@danielricecodes's advice is probably still valid but way more invasive.

Answer (score 0):

One option is you could disable the asset pipeline:

```rb
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Alternatively, if you don't use the Rails Asset Pipleine (`sprockets`, `sprockets-rails`) at all, you can remove those gems. That will remove the `assets:precompile` Rake task, and Heroku will skip it because it can't find it ([source - since Rails 4](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/951fc728979695990c32df2d4d60ae2d6f6f61c2/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb#L70))

Remove `sprockets` and `sprockets-rails` to remove the definition of `assets:precompile`. The bad news is that there's no way to easily remove just these gems since they come pre-packaged with `rails`. And by default `rails` requires several gems, including the rake task. However, you can opt to list out rails dependencies by name individually, and you can exclude `sprockets` from the list:

```rb
require 'rails'
require 'active_record/railtie'
require 'active_storage/engine'
require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'action_view/railtie'
require 'action_mailer/railtie'
require 'active_job/railtie'
require 'action_cable/engine'
require 'action_mailbox/engine'
# require 'sprockets/railtie' <--- Comment out or remove this
require 'action_text/engine'

require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'
```

**NOTE**: As of `7.0.0-alpha3`, `sprockets` is automatically excluded. See [the commit that removed `sprockets`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43261/commits/579fe208c91a0e6e941830ad5dc744c289257939), from DHH