# Assets pipeline is turned off but "error compiling assets"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, assets

The `production.rb` of my Rails 4 app contains the following configuration:

```
  config.serve_static_files = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  # config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  # config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  # config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.enabled = false
```

Yet I have an error `Error Compiling CSS asset ... .css` at heroku.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information about the error you get. It's not possible to answer with the given information.

Comment: Well, look at main.css, there is an error in there. Please look at the relevant part of main.css or post that here, if you don't understand it.

Comment: @martin, as you can see, I disabled css compiling. It's working well on localhsot.

Comment: @MarioHonse You did not turn off assets compiling.. Please follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687972/how-disable-assets-compilation-on-heroku, you have *config.assets.enabled = false* instead of *config.assets.compile = false*, then my answer make sense, because your Sass Compiler works and throw this error..

Comment: @JanStrnádek, how what I did different from that answer?

Comment: You have *config.assets.enabled = false* instead of *config.assets.compile = false* .

Comment: @JanStrnádek, it's commented out

Answer (score -1):

This is not a problem with assets pipeline, you have invalid SASS file! Please check your parentheses. It will be sth like this

```
.test-div {
  .novinka {
    padding-top: 10px;

}
```